# regex required for fetching value in </span>

Tags: regex

I need a regex for fetching the value in the `</span>` tag

```
<span class="booking-id-value">U166097</span>
```

value required: `U166097`

can please someone suggest me. I have tried using

```
<span class="booking-id-value">(.+?)
```

but it is not deriving the desired result it display on "U"

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression for this in the first place?

Comment: why are you using regular expressions instead of a proper HTML parser?

Comment: `?` after the `.+` makes it ungreedy, tells it to match as little as possible - and that’s just the first `U` in this case. Remove the `?`, and instead look for the closing `</span>` after `(.*)` to terminate what is matched correctly. https://regex101.com/r/vt4pgN/1/

Comment: @BryanOakley : to pass the value as the post regular extractor in jmeter for dynamic value selection

Comment: Try `<span class="booking-id-value">([^<]+)` instead ;).

Comment: @CBroe : I didn't not get this can you regular expression. How Should i go with this.

Comment: @CBroe : Thank you soo much

Comment: @shA.t : Thank you... :)

Comment: Please be more specific about your expected value, is it always some alphabetic and numeric characters ?

Comment: @shA.t : yeah sure.. i will :)

Comment: As other comments already said: although regex might work, it's not the best tool to parse html/xml. Unless you are doing this to learn about regex, the best approach is to use a html/xml parser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7605325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be more specific about your expected value - below I'll just accept alphabetic and numeric characters as value - and more flexible about your tag, then I can suggest you to use a regex like this:

```
/<\s*span.+?class\s*=\s*"\s*booking-id-value\s*".*?>/s*([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*<\//
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vt4pgN/3)

Answer (score 0):

`?` after the `.+` makes it ungreedy, tells it to match as little as possible - and that’s just the first `U` in this case.

Remove the `?`, and instead look for the closing `</span>` after `(.*)` to terminate what is matched correctly:

```
<span class="booking-id-value">(.+)<\/span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/vt4pgN/1/

Comment: You should keep it ungreedy, otherwise it won't work on inputs with multiple closing spans, it will go straight from the first to the last.

Comment: @JulianZucker you’re right, did not take that into account. Would only be a problem if there where no line breaks in between though, unless you make the dot match line breaks as well. If we can assume that those spans in question don’t contain any line breaks _inside_, it will still work though. But you are right, depending on the exact requirements this might need further adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
<span.*>(.*)<\/span>
```

Substitute with:

```
$1
```

[Result](https://regex101.com/r/kAQuvJ/1)